# SCSS : display-flex stacks elements on top of each other

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, flexbox

Due to some reason, the display flex property is stacking the elements on top of each other.
Also, when I specify space-between, it spreads out unevenly.

## Codepen link

### [here](https://codepen.io/karankumarshreds/pen/abmqJVN)

Incase you want to see here :

> html :

```html
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="cards__card">
        <div class="cards__card-side cards__card-side-front cards__card-side-front--1">
          <h1>Side1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cards__card-side cards__card-side-back cards__card-side-back--1">
          <h1>Side2 </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cards__card">
        <div class="cards__card-side cards__card-side-front cards__card-side-front--1">
          <h1>Side1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cards__card-side cards__card-side-back cards__card-side-back--1">
          <h1>Side2 </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> scss:

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid green;
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  /* single card wrapper*/
  &__card {
    perspective: 150rem; // put a high value
    -moz-perspective: 150rem; // to make it work on firefox
    height: 20rem; // same height as side-height
    position: relative;
    &-side {
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 24px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
      background-color: khaki;
      height: 20rem;
      width: 15rem;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      &-front {
        &--1 {
          background-color: lightgreen;
        }
      }
      &-back {
        // back side means it is already rotated 180deg
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        &--1 {
          background-color: lightcoral;
        }
      }
    }
    &:hover &-side {
      &-front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
      &-back {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
      }
      box-shadow: 0px 10px 24px -8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
  }
}
```

I am a backend engineer, so apologies if If there's some silly mistake on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex isn't the issue here, all your card faces have a position absolute property, causing them to overlap.

```
.cards__card-side {
    position: relative;
}

.cards__card-side-back {
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rod911/pen/mdrXWLX

Comment: This worked. But I have one major doubt, isn't ```position: relative``` is supposed to be on the parent element in order to position the child element as ```position: absolute``` ?
Here, you fixed it by giving same element relative and absolute position. They just have different classnames

Comment: @KaranKumar True, But you need to remember that position absolute removes the element from the document space/flow, which means the relative position parent itself will have 0 width and height, so you need to have a fixed width and height on the relative parent if all its children are absolute. That or have atleast one non-absolute child that can give the parent some width and height (what I did with your example, looking back I think it would've been easier to understand if I had given the `-front` class relative instead of `-side` class.

Comment: Understood. Thanks alot.